# Adding specific children of column to bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is a code for login/register screen. My problem is that i want to have the last to buttons always on a specific part of the screen (like bottom for example). The layout should be:

1.Some text/logo close to the top (always on the same place)

2.Inputs on the center of the screen

3.Buttons close to the bottom (always on the same place)

I have tried using the align widget or putting the 3 parts of the layout to 3 specific column with .spaceEvenly but i didnt have any success. In both of these versions nothing happends.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
print("Building login screen");
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xff34056D)),
    child: Form(
      autovalidate: true,
      key: _formKey,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32, 96, 32, 0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Fitness Companion",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 32),
              _authMode == AuthMode.Register ? _buildDisplayNameField() : Container(),
              _buildEmailField(),
              _buildPasswordField(),
              _authMode == AuthMode.Register ? _buildConfirmPasswordField() : Container(),
              SizedBox(height: 32),
              ButtonTheme(
                minWidth: 200,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  onPressed: () => _submitForm(),
                  child: Text(
                    _authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'Login' : 'Register',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              ButtonTheme(
                minWidth: 200,
                child: FlatButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    '${_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'No account yet? Register here!' : 'Already registered? Login here!'}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _passwordController.clear();
                      _authMode = _authMode == AuthMode.Login ? AuthMode.Register : AuthMode.Login;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution by try and error thats my solution:

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text("item1"),
      Expanded(child: Container()),
      Text("item2"),
      Expanded(child: Container()),
      Text("item3"),
    ],
  )
```

just put a expanded widget between the widgets you want to align.

hope it helped

Comment: It wont work because in original code Column is in SingleChildScrollView, so we can't use Expanded in Unbounded parent widget